# How to add to email content my data from form?

Tags: python, django

```
if form.is_valid():
    name = form.cleaned_data['name']
    phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
    email = form.cleaned_data['email']
    content = form.cleaned_data['content']

    subject = 'Subject'
    body = 'Your data: name: name, phone: phone, your question: content'
```

How to add to email content my data from form (name, phone and content)?

Answer (score 0):

```
body = "Your data: name: %s, phone: %s, your question: %s" % (name, phone, content)
```

or

```
body = "Your data: name: " + name + ", phone: " + str(phone) + ", your question: " + content
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
"Your String".format()
```

it works fine both for old and new python version

Answer (score 0):

The most pythonic way is using `string.format()`

Like so:

```
first_name = 'Peter'
last_name = 'Pan'
email = 'peter.pan@wunderland.com'

body = 'Hello, my name is {first_name} {last_name}. Send me a mail to {email}.'.format(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=email)
```

You can also pass a `dict` in `string.format()`.